# Capturar StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, exceção

Estou com problema de ***StackOverFlowException*** em uma aplicação **ASP.NET MVC** e não consigo achar o que pode estar ocasionando isso. Instalei o **Elmah** como sugerido em outro tópico sobre o mesmo problema, porém ele não consegue capturar, pois o *pool* da aplicação acaba caindo e desta forma o sistema não fica mais operável (nem pra gerar um *log*). Vi que existe uma ferramenta chamada **ADPlus**, mas não sei como configurar e não achei um artigo que me atendesse.

Como necessidade, comecei a gerar *logs* de todos os ***requests*** para verificar se era alguma página específica que gerava o erro e quando a aplicação caísse, tentaria verificar qual dos ***requests*** anteriores ao horário que o pool caiu (que verifico pelo ***Event Viewer*** do **IIS**) pudesse estar causando isto, mas não consegui simular. Não sei se é alguma operação disparada que fica rodando por um bom tempo até dar este tipo de exceção.

Gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar em como utilizar algum tipo de analisador (**ADPlus** de preferência) e tentar descobrir a origem deste problema.

### Atualização 17/05

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        //Adicionei este filtro para capturar todos os requests para tentar descobrir com o horário (quando o pool caísse) se era alguma página que estava dando algum loop infinito, mas não consegui
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    }
    //Metodo que captura erros a nivel de sistema
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
            return;

        var desc = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            desc += "User Identity = " + User.Identity.GetUserId() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        desc += "IP = " + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress + Environment.NewLine;
        //Gero um logo para erros a nível de sistema (mas para o stackoverflow nem funciona, pois o pool cai e a aplicação também
        ExceptionHelper.CriarArquivoExceptionServer(exc.Message, desc);

        if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.site.com.br");
        }

            Response.Write("A página que você tentou acessar não pode ser exibida. Acesse o site www.site.com.br\n");

            Server.ClearError();
        }

        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new FilterAllActions());
        }

        //este e para um problema que estava tendo de autenticação entre http/https (mas ja foi resolvido através do stackoverflow mesmo)
        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie");
            //aqui só estou forçando a flag Secure do cookie de autenticação a ser "false" para poder compartilhar-lo entre http/https
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Secure == true)
            {
                cookie.Secure = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Filtro para Gravação dos Requests (chamado pelo RegisterGlobalFilters no Global.asax):

```
public class FilterAllActions : IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{
    //A ideia e gravar um log antes de executar um request, pois se eu for verificar o horário que o pool caiu, posso ter noção de qual página próximo a queda algum usuário acessou (tudo isso para garantir se não é alguma página que está sofrendo de loop infinito e gerando o overflow)
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var url = "Inicio: " + "Metodo: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod  + " | URL: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + " | Action:  " + action + " | " + "IP: " + ObterEnderecoIp() + " | " + "Id: " + filterContext.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name + " | Browser: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser;
        ExceptionHelper.CriarArquivoRequestServer(url);
        //
    }
    //A ideia deste metodo é garantir que o método foi finalizado 
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var url = "Fim: " + "Metodo: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod + " | URL: " +  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + " | Action:  " + action + " | " + "IP: " + ObterEnderecoIp() + " | " + "Id: " + filterContext.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name + " | Browser: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser;
        ExceptionHelper.CriarArquivoRequestServer(url);
        //
    }


    // Busco o endereço desta forma pois todos os requests batem em um firewall antes de chegar no site
    protected string ObterEnderecoIp()
    {
        var userIpAddress = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var forwardedFor = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            userIpAddress = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(forwardedFor) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : forwardedFor.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).First();
        }
        catch
        {
            //
            userIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress ?? string.Empty;
        }

        return userIpAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar o conteúdo do teu `Global.asax` (e também `Startup.cs` caso tenha)? Se você não faz ideia do que possa ser, eu começaria tentando comentar várias partes do código até o problema parar.

Answer (score 0):

Há muito código que pode gerar exceptions, aconselho você a usar o `Log4Net` e ir verificando passo a passo do seu algoritmo. Testes unitários também ajudam bastante nestes casos.

[Configurando o Log4Net numa aplicação web](http://clayrmadeira.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/salvando-erros-da-aplicacao-com-log4net.html)